# Why mpu 9150 yaw values are not accurate?

Tags: arduino, sensors, android-sensors, mpu, tilt-sensor

Downloaded MPU library from https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib.

I graphed yaw values and its not accurate.

The graph has kept increasing,I don't think it's a right way.

Please check the below graph.

Comment: This is the correct behavior and is called [drifting](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=302824.0). You can handle this problem by creating a fusion of two or more sensor informations like gyroscope and accelerometer. You also have to apply some sort of filter, like [kalman filter](http://www.instructables.com/id/Guide-to-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-Arduino-inclu/)

Comment: No sorry, this is how programming and learning goes. Learning by doing. You will learn much more if you do it by yourself.

Comment: True, but yaw values are keep increasing.

Comment: As I already told you, you have to fuse different sensor data and apply a filter.